# Is it grammatical to omit "way" like this?

Tags: idiomatic-language

In Serenity (2005), Malcolm says to Simon:

> Malcolm: We'll be on Beaumonde in 10 hours' time,
> you can pick up your earnings and **be on your merry**.

Is it grammatical to omit "way" like this ?

Comment: Where did you get this? Source?

Comment: It's perfectly "natural" in context. The word is ***whimsical***, not "grammatical". Obviously it depends on the audience knowing what word is being dropped, but if even non-native speakers can tell, that's no problem here.

Comment: It is quite common, when being casual and jokey and, yes, whimsical, to omit the last word of a sentence, when that word will be readily guessed by a native or fluent speaker, e.g. He is annoying! He is a pain in the proverbial (arse or neck).

Comment: I've never heard this. It must be a British English idiom.